# How to refer to group in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I understand that we can use `\defgroup` key word to define a group in doxygen and add the class in this group by using key word `\addtogroup`. My question is how can I refer to this group in the documentation. For example,

```
/**
* \defgroup abc abc
*/

  /**
  * \addtogroup auxiliary_functions
  * @{
  */

 /**
 * Introduction to A. 
 */
 class A
  {

 };
/*
  * @}
*/
```

Then, in a page section, how can refer abc group?

```
/** @page tttt
*   how to refer to group abc?
*
*/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference any group by using its label. In your case, to reference the `abc` group from page `ttt` use the following

```
/** @page tttt
 *   
 * For more information, please see @ref abc
 */
```

The resulting page will contain a link to your group, the text of which will reflect the group's title (**abc** in your case).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know by using the keyword **ingroup**

```
/**
 * \ingroup abc
 * \brief   Explain why
 */
extern int VarInA;
```

You can find more here: [Grouping doc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html)